# iis 7 enable iOS app transport security

Tags: ios, iis-7

I have a website that runs iis 7 and HTTPS using an SSL certificate generated by godaddy. I'm able to access via https using any browser but when I try to access it programmatically via my iOS app, I'm getting an error saying `NSURLSession/NSURLConnection` HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802).  If it turn off app transport security in the app it works fine, but Apple is requiring all app to have this turned on starting in 2017.  How do I configure IIS7 to work properly with iOS App Transport Security?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.  There is nothing specific you have to do in IIS.  The problem that I was having was that the SSL Certificate I had from godaddy was using the SHA-1 encryption but iOS app transport security requires the SHA-2 encryption so I had to replace the SSL Certificate.